# can I count on my compiler to optimize strlen on const char *?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, llvm, strlen

In my SAX xml parsing callback (XCode 4, LLVM), I am doing a lot of calls to
this type of code:

```
static const char* kFoo = "Bar";

void SaxCallBack(char* sax_string,.....)
{
     if ( strcmp(sax_string, kFoo, strlen(kFoo) ) == 0)
     {

     }


  }
```

Is it safe to assume that strlen(kFoo) is optimized by the compiler?

(The Apple sample code
had pre-calculated strlen(kFoo), but I think this is error prone for large numbers of constant strings.)

Edit: Motivation for optimizing: parsing my SVG map on iPod touch 2G takes 5 seconds (!) using NSXMLParser. So, I want to switch to lib2xml, and optimize the string comparisons.

Comment: Optimisation advice to beginners: don't. Optimisation advice to experts: not yet. Unless profiling has shown this is where the bottle neck is in your program, I think you shouldn't be worrying about it.

Comment: You mean `strncmp`, right? Because you could just use `strcmp` (with two arguments) and it would be equivalent to the condition as currently written.

Comment: @freespace The question is "Can I count on my compiler to optimize...?". Unless you think that this advice applies to compilers, I do not see how it is relevant to this question.

Comment: It is almost never safe to assume that something will be optimized by a compiler, unless the language standard dictates it or you checked that it worked 10 times before. So my advice is just to check the generated assembly :)

Comment: If it matters, you can check it. But it won't matter unless that code is called a zillion times in a "real-time" system. And even then, there are propably many places where manual optimizations help more. It's not like those string constants are a hundred words long.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq it is relevant to the root cause of the question: that Jacko believes it requires opimtising, which is why he is asking if the compiler will do it for him. I believe there is value in understanding when to investigate compiler optimisations, and when to investigate algorithm optimisations, and when to not waste time on optimisation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If by "LLVM" you mean clang, then yes, you can count on `clang -O` to optimize the `strlen` away. Here is what the code for your function looks like:

```
_SaxCallBack:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rsi
    movl    $3, %edx
    callq   _strncmp
    ...
```

I changed the `strcmp` into `strncmp`, but the third argument has indeed been replaced by the immediate `$3`.

Note that gcc 4.2.1 -O3 does not optimize this `strlen` call, and that you can only expect it to work in the precise conditions of your question (especially, the string and the call to `strlen` must be in the same file).

Comment: I checked the Microsoft compiler.  It also optimized the call when using `/O2` optimization.

Comment: gcc optimises the `strlen()` call away if `kFoo` itself is made `const` (ie. `static const char * const kFoo = "Bar";`).

Comment: `clang version 2.8` doesn't optimize `strlen()` without the second `const` on my machine.

Comment: GCC 4.5 and higher does optimize it according to a quick test on gcc.godbolt.org: http://goo.gl/c9dgiq

Answer (score 13):

Don't write things like:

```
static const char* kFoo = "Bar";
```

You've created a *variable* named `kFoo` that points to constant data. The compiler might be able to detect that this variable does not change and optimize it out, but if not, you've bloated your program's data segment.

Also don't write things like:

```
static const char *const kFoo = "Bar";
```

Now your variable `kFoo` is `const`-qualified and non-modifiable, but if it's used in position independent code (shared libraries etc.), the contents will still vary at runtime and thus it will add startup and memory cost to your program. Instead, use:

```
static const char kFoo[] = "Bar";
```

or even:

```
#define kFoo "Bar"
```

Comment: I would not recommend the `#define` option in C++, definitely not! Thanks for the heads up on the pointer issue.

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++. But yeah, I would prefer the `static const char []` form anyway.

Comment: Why doesn't "static const char kFoo[]" have the position independent code problem?

Comment: The issue of `static const char *` is that you create an actual variable in the data segment whose *contents* are the address of another static-storage-duration object (the string literal). This value varies depending on the load address, so it must be patched in (via a relocation) at load time. With `static const char []`, the address does not reside in any static-storage-duration object, and code referring to the array can access it via a clean position-independent PC-relative address that's fixed at link time.

Comment: @R.. As far as I understand, declaring an array on the other hand causes at least GCC to actually copy the entire literal on the stack, chunk by chunk. In that case one has to weigh whether one wants to pay the penalty of code patching or stack allocation. Am I right?

Comment: @amn: You would be right if we were talking about objects with automatic storage duration, but these have static storage duration.

Comment: Right, missed that. Nevertheless, what do you think about the fact that statically allocated storage, according to C99, is initialized with `0`s? That's a cost to pay as well, is it not?

Comment: Static storage is always initialized. The value makes no difference to cost on any reasonable implementation.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can't count on it. However, you could use 'sizeof' and apply it to a string literal. Of course, this mean that you can't define 'kFoo' the way it originally was defined.

The following should work on all compilers and on all optimization levels.

```
#define kFoo "..."

    ... strcmp(... sizeof(kFoo))
```

Comment: Note that in this case `sizeof(kFoo) == strlen(kFoo) + 1` (`sizeof` includes the terminating `NUL`)