# Whats the best way to do strlen(const)?

Tags: c, string, constants

I am creating a C program with some hardcoded parameters. (This is by design, lets not worry about that.)

```
//global constants
const char * const USERNAME = "username";
const int USERNAME_LEN = strlen(USERNAME);
```

Of course, this errors out because strlen isn't a constant apparently. Is there a way to do this? or should I just not care and pass strncmp the result direct from strlen?

Comment: Just to be clear, this problem doesn't arise because "strlen isn't a constant". The function signature for `strlen` (on my system, and I suspect most others as well) is `size_t strlen(const char *__s)`. The problem you're having is that you can't initialize a `const` at run-time. You can only initialize it with a constant expression that is known at compile-time.

Comment: What is the reason that strlen can't be run at compile time for a global constant? (I think I get the reason, but I don't know the verbiage)

Comment: The whole point of the `const` keyword is to declare an object whose value cannot be changed at run-time. So the compiler needs to be able to determine its value at compile-time.

Comment: and why exactly can't strlen be run at compile time? Is it possible to declare a function that can be run at compile time or is that not a feature of the language? @MikeHolt

Comment: Some compilers will optimise away the call to `strlen` at compile time in these situations.  But the behaviour is not guaranteed.  If you're interested, in C++ this kind of problem can now be solved with `constexpr`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25891133/1553090

Comment: @paddy, thanks I think this clear things up. :)

Comment: @paddy: Do you have a specific compiler name? I do not think it's covered by the standard. `$ gcc -std=c11  test.c` `test.c:8:19: warning: initializer element is not a constant expression [enabled by default]` `const size_t cl = strlen(ca);` gcc does not.

Comment: You might read about the differences about compiled and interpreted languages. You could use a macro as I supposed, if you have multiple such definitions.

Comment: @Olaf, I think all paddy is saying is that if you run -O3, gcc will optimize the strlen call out of the resulting code... not that the gcc will compile this code without issue.

Comment: "`gcc -std=c11  -O3 test.c -lncurses` `test.c:8:19: warning: initializer element is not a constant expression [enabled by default]` `const size_t cl = strlen(ca);`" - Which version of gcc do you actually run to get not complaint? And, yes, although this is "just" a warning, I do not expect this to run properly. From the standard, it is UB at best. (Still wonder why this is not an error ... hmm).

Comment: @Olaf you're confusing the conversation. This is always going to get a complaint. All that is being said is that if you use strlen on a constant (within a method or something), the call will probably get optimized out in the resulting asm.

Comment: There is nothing to "optimize out" here, as there is no code generated for this! All the compiler does is to calculate the expression at compile-time and place the resulting value into the file at the position the variable is located (at run-time). That is actually the reason why that has to be a _constant expression_. Nothing to confuse about. Just have a look at the data in your debugger or objdump.

Comment: @Olaf, calculating the expression at compile time instead of actually calling the function at runtime is the optimization. I think we're just being bad at communicating.

Comment: You forget that the compiler does **not** even **know** the function definition, unless it is specified `static`. And even then, it had to execute it ("C interpreter"). For strlen(), the compiler might speculate for a hosted environment (still very dangerous), but what for a freestanding environment? `strlen` could very well do something completely different. There is no bytecode interpreter as for Java and Python. And the run-time does not provide any services for language execution as C++ does.

Comment: @Olaf, Specific to functions in the C standard library, there can be compiler specific optimizations that will optimize out these calls. Do an strlen on a constant with -O3 and look at the consulting asm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770709/can-i-count-on-my-compiler-to-optimize-strlen-on-const-char Take a look at this. @olaf

Comment: Read my comment. I _did_ run gcc -O3 on that case. And do get the same result as without. No surprise, as optimization must not deviate from the standard. Your example is a **function execution**, i.e. generated code. That is something **completely different** from a const initializer! In fact, the only one to optimize this finally away might be the linker. You might, however, refer to LTO. But that is still linker-based (as the name implies). I would instantly trash a compiler making unsafe assumptions about function semantics just by name.

Comment: Why discuss, just read the [**standard**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p3). This appies to your code, but not the example given.

Comment: You ran gcc -O3, but where is your .s output? The optimization doesn't happen until after that error comes out. @Olaf It also looks like gcc might not even do this, you might have to use microsoft's compiler or something else.

Comment: No! If you do not stick to the standard, you are in the realm of **undefined behaviour**. There anything can happen. There is no need to inspect the output once you're there.

Comment: Note that VC is not standard compatible. I will definitively _not_ use a broken non-standard "compiler", nor will I discuss aside the standard for this, as that will lead nowhere. Even _if_ that would produce code for the architectures I use actually.

Comment: Wow...  I make one innocent comment and look what happens. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need your `USERNAME` as a `const char * const` object (do you?), then one way to it is

```
#define USERNAME_LITERAL "username"

const char * const USERNAME = USERNAME_LITERAL;
const int USERNAME_LEN = sizeof USERNAME_LITERAL - 1;
```

It is as elegant as one might wish, but does keep the code in "self-maintaining" shape. I.e. you only have to edit the literal, the rest will update itself automatically.

You can also do

```
const char USERNAME[] = "username";
const int USERNAME_LEN = sizeof USERNAME - 1;
```

or even

```
#define USERNAME "username"
const int USERNAME_LEN = sizeof USERNAME - 1;
```

but in this case `USERNAME` is not `const char * const` anymore, which is why I'm asking whether you really need it as such.

Comment: I do not need a const char* const. Thanks, this helps.

Comment: Why not combine both: `const char un_lit[] = "...", *un_ptr = un_lit; size_t un_size = sizeof(un_lit);`? (Note: sizeof() returns `size_t`, which is unsigned.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but why the "un_" , out of curiosity? @Olaf

Comment: @user606723: **u**ser**n**ame. I do not use all-uppercase for variables. This is reserved for constants.

Comment: @Olaf: You are right, we can get rid of `#define` entirely. I sometimes prefer `#define` since it allows me to use the constant in concatenation context, like `#define USERNAME_WITH_SUFFIX USERNAME "Esqure"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to initialize a pointer for the literal, you can use the following:

```
const char un_str[] = "...", *un_ptr = un_str;
const size_t un_len = sizeof(un_str);
```

Note: `sizeof()` returns a size_t, which is unsigned.

You can pack that into a macro:

```
#define STR_LEN_PAIR(name, value) const char name##_str[] = value; \
        const size_t name##_len = sizeof(name##_str)
```

This uses argument concatenation. Note the missing `;` after the last line which allows to use standard syntax on invocation. Be careful to use it only as intended:

```
// at file level
STR_LEN_PAIR(un,"...");
```

The fields can be accessed like `un_len`, `un_str`, ...

Note that the pointer itself is not const, so there is not much use in it (you quite likely do not want to have a modifyable pointer to each such string). You can simply omit its definitions as I already did in the *macro.

**Compatibility note:**

C differs in the semantics of `const`. Actually, C does not have "constants" as C++ has. objects defined as `const` are actually "unmodifyable variables": they can only be initialized at compiler-time, but they consume space as any other variable (however, they might be located in unchangeable memory) and the compiler will generate read accesses as for any other variable. In C++, `un_len` for instance will be replaced by its value at compile-time and might consume no memory in the final program - as long as its address is not taken.

What comes next to real constants in C are either `enum` constants, or `#define'ed names. The latter are processed at a very different level (textual replacement by the pre-processor), however.